# Pass JSON data from API to Template in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

im new to Django and im trying to get a template filled with data comming from an API.
The data looks like this:

```
{'incident': {'collection_in': {'@COUNT': '2',
                                '@START': '1',
                                '@TOTAL_COUNT': '9',
                                'in': [{'@COMMON_NAME': '1',
                                        '@REL_ATTR': 'cr:0.1',
                                        '@id': '1'
                                       **SOME EXTRA DATA**
                                      }],
                                 'in':['@COMMON_NAME': '2',
                                        '@REL_ATTR': 'cr:0.2',
                                        '@id': '2'
                                        **SOME EXTRA DATA**
                                      }]
    }
  }
}
```

This is my views.py

```
def index(request):

    access_key = '#'

    rest = "/in?WC=group.id%3DU'F909D6A3414DC34BBD39A4D7BA4A663D'"
    get_headers = {
        "X-AccessKey":access_key,
        'Accept':"application/json",
        "X-Obj-Attrs": "*"
    }
    proxys = {
             #
    }
    response2 = requests.get("http://XXXXXXXX/caisd-rest/"+rest, 
                            headers=get_headers,proxies=proxys)
    return render(request,'incident/index.html',context={'incident':json.loads(response2.content)})
```

And my template:

```
<ul>
{% for key in incident.collection_in.in %}
   <li>{{key.@id}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I have tried multiple ways, but i cant access the values or i get this error:
Could not parse the remainder: '@id' from 'key.@id'

if i remove the @id, from key.@id, i get all the data, but im only interested in this case at the ids
How do i do this or what im missing?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "but im only interested in this case at the ids"? Is it possible you can change the value in the json to remove the "@" symbol? That seems to be messing it up.

Comment: Hello, i cant remove the "@" symbol as the API we need to consult is not our own. And im only interested in the IDs because my end result need to be something like a list of all the IDs there.